# how to create a task directly from sugarcrm?

Tags: calendar, sugarcrm

Is there anyway to create a task directly from SugarCRM Calendar in the similar way in which we can can create a call or meeting.

Directly means using te popup window which gets opened when we click on a cell in Calendar dashlet, where there are only two radio buttons for creating a meeting or a call.

Comment: No, not without customization of the Calendar interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can achieve this functionality but for that you have to customize the template of Popup in **Calenders module** and also customize the process to create the Tasks.
But these changes will be **non-upgrade safe** changes. 
On Sugar upgrade these changes will not reflect in the upgraded version